# How to using facebook sdk on cocos2dx-project

Tags: facebook, cocos2d-x

I'm doing game cocos2d-x, when user get high score, i want them touch on fb icon and share high score on account facebook.

but, tutorial on facebook.developer.com using for objective-c project.

So anybody help me:(

Comment: Your question is too broad. Refer to this excellent article that will help you form a better question (and hence get better help). http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can call objective-c code from c++ without any problem. So, I think all you need is just add fb library to iOS project and call objective-c code from your game.

Look an example how you call objective-c code from cocos2d-x here: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/11655

I found another example [Creating InAppPurchase in Cocos2d-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815309/creating-inapppurchase-in-cocos2d-x)