# Creating InAppPurchase in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, cocos2d-x

I am new to Cocos2d-x.I need to create InAppPurchase For Cocos2d-x iOS game (CPP).can anybody help me to create InAppPurchase.or any Tutorials Related to this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: write bridge c++ class in .mm file and write inAp purchase as it is in obj.C in .m file. It works..Happy coding.

Comment: @Guru-I did like that.but i'm getting errors as NSObject.h,NSZone.h,NSObjCRuntime.h..Also added foundationframework to #ifdef_OBJC_ in .pch file.any solution or new tutorials?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784621/inapp-purchase-in-cocos2d-x..screenshot of that error.

Comment: its easy, just add #include <stddef.h> in .h file and write cpp class and in .mm of cpp class call inAp in .m    remove #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

Comment: ok added my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use obj.C version of inAp purchase in .cpp cocos2d-x project. All you need to do is just write bridge cpp class in .mm file. It works for iOS.

//.cpp file say Player.cpp

```
#include "MyGameBride.h"

 void Player::unlockPlayer()
 {
     MyGameBride:: shared()-> upgrade_inAp();
 }
```

//.h of MyGameBride.h

```
#include <stddef.h>

class MyGameBride
{
    public:
        MyGameBride();
        MyGameBride();

        static MyGameBride* shared();
        void upgrade_inAp();
};
```

// MyGameBride.mm  (note that here .mm not .m )

```
 #import "MyGameBride.h"

    static MyGameBride *s_gc;


  MyGameBride* MyGameBride::shared(){
        if (! s_gc) {
            s_gc = new MyGameBride();
        }
        return s_gc;
    }


 void GameCenter:: upgrade_inAp(){
        AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [app upgrade];
    }
```

Here AppController is objective class in .m

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/dualface/cocos2d-x-extensions that includes store extension download and browse, it will help you.

All the best..

Comment: @iphonic-Thanks.i'll try this.also if i face any problem or issues i'll contact you.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm biased (I'm one of the creators) but cocos2dx-store is exactly what you need: http://github.com/soomla/cocos2dx-store

Comment: Just starting developing with soomla and looks pretty well.
Congrats!

Comment: @refaelos This is a nice framework, but do you have WinRT support on the roadmap?  Cocos2d-x has recently started supporting WinRT as well.